# How to limit application usage for a SaaS with per-seat based approach?

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, session-cookies, saas

I'm working on my enterprise SaaS application and some of my users would like to be charged on a per-seat approach.

I was wondering how to make sure that the access will indeed be limited. I can see right now that people with the same login/password are logging from different IP addresses, different user agents at the same time, even though the company have paid only for one seat.

What would be the best way to implement the limitation from business and technical perspectives? I don't want to be too strict, at the same time I want companies to pay for the number of seats they actually need.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using? (php/java/ruby/...)

Comment: It's PHP, and logins are implemented with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Don't filter by user agent, I think that would be too strict, some people may have a variety of browsers installed. Filtering by IP could also be tricky, some users may have a dynamic IP that changes at regular intervals.

One idea I have would be to force users to install a browser extension, the browser extension could generate a unique ID from something on the operating system. Maybe use a HDD volume number or Windows serial key, anything that will be unique to that computer.

Once you have this unique ID, use it in the back end tracking every time the user logs in. If the user exceeds a certain number of seats you can either block the user account or contact them first.

It would also be a good idea to allow the user a certain amount of freedom, so that if they have one seat then the back end will allow maybe 2 seats for a month (rolling period), this would be in-case the user buys a new pc or installs a new HDD.

Comment: Commonly a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is used as the generated identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Using IP seems a bad idea - people in a LAN will (usually) all have the same IP.

Assuming PHP has no API to access inspect sessions different than the current one - one idea is:

- if you're not already doing it, for each login cookie you issue, also issue an unique id (an UUID will serve your purpose)
- store those ids somewhere (in java you could store them in the application context, maybe in php you'll need a db table for that - I'm no php expert), together with two timestamps: "session start" and "last activity"
- at each request, record the current timestamp in "last activity"

Then, when you get a new request, count how many other active have

- `last activity >= current session start`
- `last activity >= now - session TTL` (only needed if can't prune expired sessions in a timely fashion)

That should give you the number of occupied seats.

Note you will *not* notice a violation of the number of seats until *after* the surplus user has logged in and precisely until you see activity in some other session – I don't see any way around this issue since you don't know exactly when a seat becomes vacant (well, you might say it's vacant only when its session has expired, but that seems unfair).

Answer (score 0):

There are also a number of software providers if you want to oursource your account sharing solution:

- Castle
- Arkose Labs
- Verisoul
- Seon

Etc. etc. - there are a ton! Most are pretty affordable solutions as well.